# Minimum number of operations to make two arrays equal

Tags: arrays, algorithm, minimization

Given 2 arrays of integers, **A**  and **B**, an operation on array B is defined as follows:

**B[i] = B[i]+2** and **B[j] = B[j]-2**, where **i != j**

- i and j can be any indices and the above operation can be performed
  any number of times such that i and j are not equal
- **a valid operation consists of both the addition and subtraction steps, both parts are mandatory**

The array is considered equal if the frequency of all the elements is same, the array need not be ordered, find the minimum operations required

**Input:**

**A = [ 2, 10, 14 ]**

**B =  [ 6, 2, 18 ]**

**Output: 2**

**Explanation :**

```
1st operation:  select i=0; j=2; 
B[i] += 2 i.e B[0]=8;
B[j] -= 2 i.e B[2] = 16;
B after 1st operation [8,2,16]

2nd operation:  select i=0; j=2; 
B[i] += 2 i.e B[0]=10;
B[j] -= 2 i.e B[2] = 14;
B after 2nd operation [10,2,14]
```

Order doesnt matter, so we have made the arrays equal return 2;

I am unable get an approach to solve this and couldn't find any similar questions, so posting this here, thanks in advance.

Comment: What if it isn't possible to make the arrays equal? For example, `A` contains an odd number but `B` doesn't contain any odd numbers, or if `A = [10, 20]`, `B = [12, 22]`?

Comment: You've asked questions before, and some received answers. Any reason why you don't give feedback to them? Are they that bad?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the arrays are solvable, then sort the arrays (by parity, and then by value), add up the absolute value of the deltas and divide by 4.

E.g.

```
A = [ 2, 10, 14 ], already sorted
B = [ 6, 2, 18 ], sorted becomes [2, 6, 18]
```

Sum of absolute value of deltas = 0 + 4 + 4 = 8. 8/4 = 2 so 2 moves.

Comment: That doesn't seem to produce a nice answer when the inputs are with A=[1,1,2,2] and B=[0,1,2,3].  Your calculation produces 1+0+0+1 = 2.  2/4 moves?

Comment: @Wyck Right you are. We need to group parities. Same solution, except sort by 1) parity and then 2) value. Gets [2,2,1,1] and [0,2,1,3], with deltas of 2, 0, 0, 2, so 4/4 = 1 move, which is right.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [2, 10, 14]( % 2 == 0)
B = [2, 6, 18]( % 2 == 0)
```

another example

```
A = [1, 2, 5] -> [1, 5]( % 2 == 1) & [2]( % 2 == 0)
B = [1, 3, 4] -> [1, 3]( % 2 == 1) & [4]( % 2 == 0)
```

Notice that `(a + k) mod k == a`.

Assuming we already have a sorted array.

We divide the array into k parts, according to the mod k value of the element, then we sum all absolute differences, it's four times the answer.

```
k = 2
A.sort(key=lambda x: x % k)
B.sort(key=lambda x: x % k)
result = 0
n = len(A)
for i in range(n):
    result += abs(A[i] - B[i])
print(result >> 2)
# A = [1, 2, 5]
# B = [1, 3, 4]
# result = 1
# A = [2, 10, 14]
# B = [6, 2, 18]
# result = 2
```

O(N log N) because of sorting.